# Postgres array concatenation function

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Does Postgres have a function to transform an array into a single value? For example, I'd like to do something like:

`reduce(ARRAY['one','two'])` -> `onetwo`, or even better: `reduce(ARRAY['one','two], ', ')` -> `one, two`

If not, how would I go about implementing that in my query. I know of `unnest`, but that just gives me one row per array element

Comment: `array_to_string()`? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

Comment: Thanks, I must have been sleeping while reading that page >_<

Comment: @a_horse feel free to make that an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the comments:

```
select array_to_string(array['one','two'],',');
 array_to_string 
-----------------
 one,two
```